# Regex to match only links starting with www

Tags: regex, url, match

say i have a list of URLs like this:

```
https://www.pinterest.com/brunight/ghibli/
https://www.pinterest.com/pin/366691594633734460/
www.onlineghibli.com/
www.studioghibli.com.au/
www.ghibli-museum.jp/en/
```

I use the following regex:

```
/www.*/i
```

However it will just match the urls starting with https:// also staring at the www. part of those urls.

How could i only match the URLs from the above list starting with www. and ignore the first 2 URLs?

Comment: Your regex finds *partial* matches. Adding `^` anchor at the start and `$` at the end will fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks that works great :D